# Framework for collecting unit test output from disparate executables?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests

I've become responsible for cleaning up an old unit-testing environment. The existing environment contains a ton of executables (1000+ shell scripts, compiled binaries, etc) and each one returns code 0 or 1 and some output depending on the results. Tests can also time out. A set of PERL scripts goes through, runs each executable file, and collects the results into a big XML file which gets rendered into a web page. This system works great, but isn't very extensible or fast.

In addition to cleaning/speeding this up, I would like to implement concurrent testing. Right now the tests run one at a time. Many of the tests require resource locks (ports, files, etc) and there's no listing of which are safe to run simultaneously. An option here is to run each one in a VM of some kind.

Is there a framework or tool designed for this type of situation? What's the best way to approach it if I have to write my own brand new system? My limitation is that I cannot change the 1000+ test executables. I was thinking something like PyUnit with Python unit tests that use subprocess or similar to execute the existing tests and convert the results into a Pythonic format. Is this overkill? Could such a system support isolation of processes to avoid deadlocks and race conditions between tests? In a worst-case, I was thinking of using Python to SSH into one of several VM's to run the tests.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Edit: Python isn't strictly necessary. Another solution might just break the test set into several M-sized chunks and run each test in an independent VM over SSH until all M-sized chunks are done. I'm hoping there's a tool out there that solves this problem.

Comment: While I haven't tackled a problem exactly like the one you outline, I have tackled quite a few that are similar. Feel free to contact me if you would like to discuss this further.

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of-the-box or customize it for your needs solution of which I am aware to solve the problem you are facing.

Looking at your problem, there are several distinct needs which standout:

- Test Tagging
- Test Execution
- Test Result Capture

The first issue you need to address is how are you going to identify and track the tests that you can execute in a given environment, concurrently, etc.

If you were using [nose](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) (i.e. is nicer testing for python), you would be able to use the [Attribute selector plugin](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/attrib.html) to tag the tests with various attributes.

nose would also assist you in your test execution and when coupled with test tagging, would allow you to run tests in parallel, etc. Using nose, you should be able to run an external executable and assert based on its status code.

The final problem you face is how to capture test output in a proprietary format and translate it to a format that can be ingested to readily available tools. Again, I believe nose could help you out here. You could build a [nose plugin](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/developing.html) that would take your proprietary format and translate it to XUnit format and report results that way.

With all of the above in mind, here is how I would tackle this situation:

- Create a test wrapper class based on nose which

  - Can be tagged
  - Execute a program and capture result output
  - Translate that output to XUnit
- Create a wrapper for each test

  - Figure out how to automate this process, because it is going to be tedious
- Build a test execution harness, which

  - Spins Up one or more VMs
  - Loads and runs a test wrapper
  - Capture the results

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've been looking into Nose. Just to be clear, the test class you mentioned would be able to run any generic test, for example with subprocess, correct? Then the wrapper would provide an instance of the class for each test? I'm also a little confused about the tagging. How would I use this? To be clear, my plan is to just run each test on an independent VM to avoid having to check for conflicts.